# Reorder columns by a number embedded in their names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dataset which has following column names:

```
df

X100_TT_7.1  X50_TT_1.1  X60_TT_2.1  X80_TT_4.1  X70_TT_3.1  X85_FTT_5.1  X90_TT_6.1
    0.08        0.06        0.84        0.95        0.89        0.91        0.86
```

I want to rearrange column in below show manner i.e. as per 1.1 to 7.1 in colnames:

```
df

X50_TT_1.1  X60_TT_2.1  X70_TT_3.1  X80_TT_4.1  X85_FTT_5.1 X90_TT_6.1  X100_TT_7.1
0.06          0.84        0.89        0.95        0.91        0.86          0.08
```

I have tried to solve the same using order and substr functions but did not get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via base R,

```
df[order(sub("^.*(.*)_", "\\1", names(df)))]
#  X50_TT_1.1 X60_TT_2.1 X70_TT_3.1 X80_TT_4.1 X85_FTT_5.1 X90_TT_6.1 X100_TT_7.1
#1       0.06       0.84       0.89       0.95        0.91       0.86        0.08
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mixedorder` from `gtools` to `order` the columns

```
library(gtools)
df1 <- df[mixedorder(names(df))]
df1
#     X50_TT_1.1 X60_TT_2.1 X70_TT_3.1 X80_TT_4.1 X85_FTT_5.1 X90_TT_6.1 X100_TT_7.1
#1       0.06       0.84       0.89       0.95        0.91       0.86        0.08
```

Or if it is based only on the floating numbers

```
df[order(as.numeric( sub(".*_", "", names(df))))]
#  X50_TT_1.1 X60_TT_2.1 X70_TT_3.1 X80_TT_4.1 X85_FTT_5.1 X90_TT_6.1 X100_TT_7.1
#1       0.06       0.84       0.89       0.95        0.91       0.86        0.08
```

Comment: @Sotos I thought the OP wanted to sort based on the whole string.  Anyway, updated.

Answer (score 0):

Another base R attempt:

```
df[,order(as.numeric(lapply(strsplit(names(df),"_"),tail,1)))]

#  X50_TT_1.1 X60_TT_2.1 X70_TT_3.1 X80_TT_4.1 X85_FTT_5.1 X90_TT_6.1 X100_TT_7.1
#1       0.06       0.84       0.89       0.95        0.91       0.86        0.08
```

Comment: It seems safer to use `tail, 1` rather than `[[, 3`, i.e. `lapply(strsplit(names(df),"_"), tail, 1)`

Comment: @Sotos This is another way to do it but not more efficient I suppose. I skipped that step though, see my update.

Comment: It is not about efficiency, but rather for safety. If one of the names is for example, `X50_TT_RS_1.1` then It will fail.